# How to set up relationships between new and existing entities in EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

My application allows the user to create a hierarchy of new entities via a UI - let's say it's a "Customer" plus one or more child "Order" entities. The user also assigns each Order entity to an existing "OrderDiscount" entity (think of these as "reference"/"lookup" items retrieved from the database). Some time later, the user will choose to save the whole hierarchy to the database, accomplished like this:-

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    context.Customers.Add(customer);

    foreach (var entity in context.OrderDiscounts.Local)
    {
        objectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Unchanged);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The `foreach` loop changes the state of the OrderDiscount entities to Unchanged, and prevents EF from attempting to insert them into the database, resulting in duplicates.

Great so far, but I've now hit another issue. For reasons I won't go into, the OrderDiscount entities can come from different BLL calls, resulting in a situation where two Orders in the graph may *appear* to reference the same OrderDiscount (i.e. both have the same PK ID, and other properties), but the entities are different object references.

When I save, the above `foreach` loop fails with the message *"AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges"*. I can see the two OrderDiscount objects in the `context.OrderDiscounts.Local` collection, both with the same PK ID.

I'm not sure how I can avoid this situation. Any suggestions?

This article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx) describes the scenario and provides one possible solution, which is to set just the FK ID (`order.OrderDiscountId`), and leave the `order.OrderDiscount` relationship null. Unfortunately it's not feasible in my case, as further down the line I rely on being able to traverse such relationships, e.g. `ApplyDiscount(order.OrderDiscount);`.

Comment: You should still be able to "traverse such relationships" after setting the foreign key because EF synchronises the navigation properties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: @Colin unfortunately I'm working in a "disconnected" manner - the object graph is being created in the UI tier, so there is no context available to perform the syncing. I have to manually "fix up" each relationship - FK ID, navigation property, etc. I suspect it's going to be a rewrite to ensure that the same "lookup" entity instances are always served up, or a move to something like RavenDB which may be more suited to working with large entity graphs.

Comment: You can vote for better support for working with disconnected entities here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864 and there is a link to an open source solution. But I'm afraid I am not qualified in this area.